# How to get username of two different ids

Tags: entities

I have created a block inside a module and in that, I just need to get usernames of two different Ids

```
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($id_1);
$account_2 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($id_2);
$tenant_name = $account_2->getUsername();
$owner_name = $account->getUsername();
```

I have used this code.

Comment: So you mention an error. What error? Where are you calling that code?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you are getting an error from code you wrote, you should tell us which error you are getting and which line is exactly causing it. Without that information, we can just guess: The variable containing the user ID could be not initialized, or there could not be any user with that ID, or you are seeing a depreciation message telling you which method should instead be used. It could also be the error is not even caused by the shown code; in that case, telling you what is causing the error becomes quite difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getUsername()` is deprecated and returns the below error

> \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface::getUsername() is deprecated in
>   Drupal 8.0.0, will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0. Use
>   \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface::getAccountName() or
>   \Drupal\user\UserInterface::getDisplayName() instead. See
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/2572493

The correct way to get user/account name from user object is to call its `getAccountName()` function.

**Example:**

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$account = User::load($user_id);
$name = $account->getAccountName();
```